# Can a website company that builds 4-5 websites a year afford dedicated hosting?

Tags: hosting, share

We manage about 30 websites that use shared ASP.NET SQL Server web hosting. These are typical small/medium business websites and they perform fine in this environment. They average around 1Gb outbound a month.

Recently I was looking at VPS hosting in this thread [How do you host multiple public facing websites on a VPS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128329/how-do-you-host-multiple-public-facing-websites-on-a-vps)

After contacting a provider in one of the replies I was told that VPS hosting is not recommended for 30 sites, even if they are small. The resource requirements might be too great even for VPS. So I should turn to dedicated hosting.

The lowest cost dedicated hosting is $219 per month (see http://www.serverintellect.com/dedicated/pentiumdservers.aspx). But this is only for a single processor which seems too light for a machine running both IIS and SQL.

In our office all the developers work on quad cores so I assume I’d really need the  Quad Processor. However, this starts at $599 monthly.

Now, I won’t be able to transfer all of our 30 sites to this machine. I’d only be able to transfer say 5 or 6. However, moving forward, I’d be able to host all future sites on this machine.  This amounts to 4-5 per year.

Let’s look at the economics. Shared hosting costs are typically $16.95 monthly (see http://www.crystaltech.com/dotnet.aspx). So here’s the dilemma

First months costs: $599

First month revenue: 6x$16.95 = $101.7

Loss in first month: $497.3

First year costs: $599x12=$7188

First month revenue: 6x$16.95x12 + 5x$16.95x6(averaged) = $1728.9

Loss in first year: $5459.1

Clearly it is going to take years for this server to pay for itself.
It just doesn’t seem economical!

Am I missing something here, or is dedicated not the way to go with the amount of sites we build?

Answer (score 3):

Petras,

The "number" of websites you are capable of hosting on a VPS is dependent on the type of load that each application is experiencing (and App Pool over head etc. too, of course). A better measure (although not definitive) would be how much traffic you are pushing - this is usually more indicative of the type of load your machine is under.

You cannot make a decision based on what someone else says is best practice. Best practice is using a solution which suitably addresses your requirements. Is the VPS too slow for you? If not, why upgrade? If the VPS **is** too slow for you, then investigate where the issue is occurring - there is a strong chance that it may not be load based and could be as simple as a configuration change.

Quincey.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to lose money, it's not the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to make the money back, there's no point. If you're honestly reaching a VPS resource limitation, my advice? Add a second VPS account.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for a moment that you really *need* this dedicated machine...

First, you can save money by purchasing your own equipment and using a co-location provider instead of renting your server.

Secondly, your pricing model should factor in the costs associated with doing business. So if you need to provide a more costly service, do what everybody else does. Raise your prices.